# How to use Asp.net Kendo ui grid resource

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to use Asp.net resource kendo ui grid in the title part.Help us.

Resource File Name: RiskManagementContent

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%22)%20%23%22&p1=is%20un…%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22title%22%3A%20%22%3Cdiv kendo-grid="" k-options="mainGridOptions" k-columns="[

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions" k-columns='[
                     { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskNumberText", "field": "RiskNo", "width": "5%"},
                     { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskDescriptionsText", "field": "RiskDescription", "width": "25%" },
                     { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskTypeText", "field": "RiskType.RiskTypeName", "width": "6%" },
                     { "title": "<div style=\"text-align center\">@RiskManagementContent.NaturalRisksText</div>",
                                   "columns": [
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                           "field": "RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                           "field": "RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       },
                                      { 
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                           "field": "RiskLevelDescription.LevelName",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       }
                                   ]
                               },
                               {
                                   "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.ResidualRiskText</div>",
                                   "columns": [
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                           "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel : "") #",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                           "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName : "") #",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                           "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskLevelDescription.LevelName : "") #",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskAppetiteText",
                                           "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskAppetite.RiskAppetiteName : "") #",
                                           "width": "6%"
                                       }
                                   ]
                               },
                               { "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.CheckText</div>", "width": "6%" },
                               { "command": [{ "name": "edit" }, { "name": "destroy" }], "width": "12%" }]'><div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad JSON string format...

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions" k-columns='[
                 { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskNumberText", "field": "RiskNo", "width": "5%"},
                 { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskDescriptionsText", "field": "RiskDescription", "width": "25%" },
                 { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskTypeText", "field": "RiskType.RiskTypeName", "width": "6%" },
                 { "title": "<div style=\"text-align center\">@RiskManagementContent.NaturalRisksText</div>",
                               "columns": [
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                       "field": "RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                       "field": "RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   },
                                  { 
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                       "field": "RiskLevelDescription.LevelName",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   }
                               ]
                           },
                           {
                               "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.ResidualRiskText</div>",
                               "columns": [
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                       "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel : \"\") #",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                       "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName : \"\") #",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                       "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskLevelDescription.LevelName : \"\") #",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskAppetiteText",
                                       "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskAppetite.RiskAppetiteName : \"\") #",
                                       "width": "6%"
                                   }
                               ]
                           },
                           { "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.CheckText</div>", "width": "6%" },
                           { "command": [{ "name": "edit" }, { "name": "destroy" }], "width": "12%" }]'><div>
```

Where you have the templates defined `"template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskAppetite.RiskAppetiteName : \"\") #"` you should escape the empty string quotes `\"\"`.

**Update**

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions" k-columns='[
             { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskNumberText", "field": "RiskNo", "width": "5%"},
             { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskDescriptionsText", "field": "RiskDescription", "width": "25%" },
             { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskTypeText", "field": "RiskType.RiskTypeName", "width": "6%" },
             { "title": "<div style=\"text-align center\">@RiskManagementContent.NaturalRisksText</div>",
                           "columns": [
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                   "field": "RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               },
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                   "field": "RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               },
                              { 
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                   "field": "RiskLevelDescription.LevelName",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.ResidualRiskText</div>",
                           "columns": [
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ImpactText",
                                   "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskImpact.RiskImpactLevel : \"\") #",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               },
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.ProbabilityText",
                                   "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskProbability.RiskProbabilityName : \"\") #",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               },
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.LevelText",
                                   "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskLevelDescription.LevelName : \"\") #",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               },
                               {
                                   "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskAppetiteText",
                                   "template": "#= (ResidueRisk != null ? ResidueRisk.RiskAppetite.RiskAppetiteName : \"\") #",
                                   "width": "6%"
                               }
                           ]
                       },
                       { "title": "<div style=\"text-align: center\">@RiskManagementContent.CheckText</div>", "width": "6%" },
                       { "command": [{ "name": "edit" }, { "name": "destroy" }], "width": "12%" }]'><div>
```

Try it using the `''` notation instead of the `\"\"`, this should also work for your purpose.

I recommend to create the columns object in an angular controller or as a java script variable and pass that to the attribute `k-columns`.

Comment: Syntax Error: Token '") #"' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 1856 of the expression [[
                         { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskNumberText", "field": "RiskNo", "width": "5%"},
                         { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskDescriptionsText", "field": "RiskDescription", "width": "25%" },
                         { "title": "@RiskManagementContent.RiskTypeText", "field": "RiskType.RiskTypeName", "width": "6%" },
                         { "title": "<div] starting at [{4}].

Comment: I added up the answer .

Comment: What is at that column 1856 in the error message? See if you can figure it out where the problem is. Also try to use it as an object and pass it to the attribute value.

Comment: An error caused by Google chrome. Thank you my friend for your response.